# HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.reddit.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp

hello im trying to caching the GET request that im doing from reddit service. I tested with another api and works but i can't find the reason why i can't have control of the cache on this one. I can see how cache data goes up in app settings when i can fecth the json with internet on. But when i turn off internet connection ( airplane mode ) i get this error:

> 01-17 06:00:05.524 17363-17429/com.amirgb.reddittestapp.debug D/OkHttp: --> GET https://www.reddit.com/reddits.json http/1.1
>   01-17 06:00:05.524 17363-17429/com.amirgb.reddittestapp.debug D/OkHttp: --> END GET
>   01-17 06:00:05.531 17363-17429/com.amirgb.reddittestapp.debug D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.reddit.com": No address associated with hostname

Im testing on a moto g 4 plus api 23 i tried with https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=20/json service and cache does work, so maybe there is a difference in reddit header? .

My restclient class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.amirgb.reddittestapp.BuildConfig;
import com.amirgb.reddittestapp.R;
import com.amirgb.reddittestapp.RedditTestApplication;
import com.amirgb.reddittestapp.model.RedditResponse;
import com.amirgb.reddittestapp.util.NetWorkUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.Cache;
import okhttp3.CacheControl;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public final class RedditApiService {

    private static IRedditApi mRedditApi;
    private static OkHttpClient mClient;

    /**
     * Inits retrofit
     */
    static {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        File httpCacheDirectory = new File(RedditTestApplication.getInstance().getCacheDir(), "reddit");
        Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024);

         mClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache)
                .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    if (NetWorkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(RedditTestApplication.getInstance())) {
                        request = request.newBuilder()
                                .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
                                        .maxAge(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                        .maxStale(365, TimeUnit.DAYS).build())
                                .build();
                    }

                    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(request);
                    if (NetWorkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(RedditTestApplication.getInstance())) {
                        int maxAge = 60 * 60;
                        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                                .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                                .build();
                    } else {
                        int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28;
                        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                                .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                                .build();
                    }
                })
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        Retrofit mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(IRedditApi.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(mClient)
                .build();
        mRedditApi = mRetrofit.create(IRedditApi.class);
    }

    /**
     * Get subjects from service api
     *
     * @param callback
     */
    public static void getSubjects(Callback<RedditResponse> callback) {
        Call<RedditResponse> call = mRedditApi.getSubjects();
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
```

My networks util method:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

My retrofit interface:

```
public interface IRedditApi {
String BASE_URL = "https://www.reddit.com";

@GET("/reddits.json")
Call<RedditResponse> getSubjects();}
```

Reddit reponse header:

> accept-ranges →bytes
>   access-control-allow-origin →*
>   access-control-expose-headers →X-Reddit-Tracking, X-Moose
>   cache-control →max-age=0, must-revalidate
>   content-encoding →gzip
>   content-length →79113
>   content-type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   date →Tue, 17 Jan 2017 09:16:52 GMT
>   status →200
>   strict-transport-security →max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
>   vary →accept-encoding
>   via →1.1 varnish
>   x-cache →MISS
>   x-cache-hits →0
>   x-content-type-options →nosniff
>   x-frame-options →SAMEORIGIN
>   x-moose →majestic
>   x-reddit-tracking →https://pixel.redditmedia.com/pixel/of_destiny.png?v=W9eORuZE%2BzXXBRZc%2BikbQ8aTR0a7BSLeoE9DDYvuCihjMAifTK%2Bdsr%2F0gX8rDES98kR5xK2vVWc%3D
>   x-served-by →cache-dfw1841-DFW
>   x-timer →S1484644612.225905,VS0,VE254
>   x-ua-compatible →IE=edge
>   x-xss-protection →1; mode=block